# c++ convert pipe to comma delimited

Tags: c++, xcode, file-conversion

I am trying to convert this pipe delimited file into comma delimited. I need to read the file into an array and then output it in comma delimited into a CSV file. I am having a very hard time with the whole conversion process so I am trying to find the simplest way that I can output the data into the comma file.

This is the input file:

```
Miles per hour|6,445|being the "second" team |5.54|9.98|6,555.00 "Ending" game| left at "beginning"| Elizabeth, New Jersey|25.25|6.78|987.01 |End at night, or during the day| "Let's go"|65,978.21|0.00|123.45 Left-base night|10/07/1900|||4.07|777.23 "Let's start it"| Start Baseball Game| Starting the new game to win
```

This is the portion of code I have so far for when the input pipe file is already open:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {

string myArray[5];

   for(int = 0; i<5, i++)
{
  file >> myArray[i];

 while (getline(input, temp, '|')) {
      if (temp.find(",") != string::npos)
         cout << '"' << temp << "\",";
      else
         cout << temp << ',';
}
```

Comment: What you have exposed doesn't look that bad (IMHO). For further insights into C++ I/O streams, a book can help or an online tutorial like e.g. this one: [A Gentle Introduction to C++ IO Streams](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c++-iostreams.html). What I'm not quite sure about: If you want to convert _one_ file why do you need an array of strings (`string myArray[5];`) and a `for` loop?

Comment: This code doesn't compile, `file`, `input` and `temp` are undeclared, `input` is also uninitialised. Very hard to offer advice when there could be important mistakes in the missing code.